# Android expandable list item circle`s color

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Does anybody knows how to change the color of Expandable List Item`s little circle with arrow? My designer asked me to do so, I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't change the arrow color, it's complicated and is a bad idea anyway because the arrow drawable might differ from device to device so the result will be unpredictable.

Instead, use the `android:groupIndicator` attribute to change the default arrow to a custom drawable :

```
<ExpandableListView ...
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator" >
```

**group_indicator.xml** can be a selector to show a different arrow if the item is expanded :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" />
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" />
</selector>
```

[This tutorial](http://android-adda.blogspot.fr/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html) will give you more details.

Comment: could you tell me how to set the height and width of this indicator?

Comment: I think the size of your drawables (arrow_right, arrow_down) will be automatically used as the size of your indicator.

Comment: I know, but I`m just curious how to set it in xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a own component (view) and override it's

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
```

Method. Now you can draw whatever you want. Of course it is a lot of work, but this will give you the most possibilities.